# How can i add imageslider in fragment and Why i do get adapter(adapter) error?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Hello I'm trying to add imageslider to my activity but i get error

Following [this tutorial..](http://kb4dev.com/article/android-image-slider-with-swipe-gesture)

In this position i get this error on line 45:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)'
>   on a null object reference

And on line 45 is:

```
sds.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my actvity.java

```
public class Sayfalar extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager,sds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sayfalar);

        sds = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.resimler);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Sayfalar.this);
        sds.setAdapter(adapter);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    public void showDialog (View v){
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"my_dialog");
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment1(), "Fragment1");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment2(), "Fragment2");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment3(), "Fragment3");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment4(), "Fragment4");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment5(), "Fragment5");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment6(), "Fragment6");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment7(), "Fragment7");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment8(), "Fragment8");
        adapter.addFrag(new Fragment9(), "Fragment9");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {


        }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is My activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/popupmenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If i add this code to my activity.xml i see my pictures in all fragments but i want it in one fragment.

Here is the code :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/resim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

And here is one of the fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Kaynaklar.Agil">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/resimler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1 () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two viewpager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can examine this code.

```
public class Sayfalar extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager,sds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sayfalar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    public void showDialog (View v){
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"my_dialog");
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {


    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment1 fragment1=Fragment1.newInstance(position);
            return fragment1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "title "+position;
        }
    }
}
```

//Fragment

```
   public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,container,false);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ImageView imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }

        public static Fragment1 newInstance(int position) {
            Fragment1 fr=new Fragment1();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position",position);
            fr.setArguments(bundle);
            return fr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: mustafasevgi benim kafa yandı galiba neyi nereye yazacagımı karıstıyorum artık. bu verdigin ilk kodda benim diger fragmentler nerede ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
sds = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.resimler);
PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Sayfalar.this);
sds.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You don't seem to have a `ViewPager` in your `sayfalar` layout with the `resimler` ID, so `sds` will be `null`, and then you're trying to call `setAdapter()` on that `null` reference.

To set up the second `ViewPager` in `Fragment1`, you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    ViewPager sds = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.resimler);
    // assuming CustomAdapter requires an Activity or Context as a constructor param
    PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());
    sds.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake. You cannot access `R.id.resimler` in your Activity since that viewPager is declared in the xml of the Fragment. (that's why you get null for this variable):

```
sds = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.resimler);
```

What you need to do in order to reference this viewPager is to migrate this code into the Fragment's method `onCreateView` like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    ViewPager sds = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.resimler);
    //and do whatever you want with the ViewPager at this point
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Hey Vucko i still see blank page when i run the app in my fragment page.

Comment: Well that's because the sds wasn't given an adapter. I just gave you the proper way to instantiate it.